# Searching a string in a binary tree in c

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-tree

I am a student of computer science, and I had an exam last week in C.

One of the questions was to search a specific word (string) in a binary tree, and count how many times it appears.

Every node in the tree contains a letter.

For example, if the word is "mom", and the tree looks like the attached image, the function should return 2.
Pay attention that if there is a word like this — "momom" — the function will count the "mom" only one time.

I have not been able to solve this question.  Can you help?

[image: The example of tree]

```
     a
    / \
  b    m
 /    / \
v    o   o
    / \   \
   m   t   m
```

Comment: So the word is in tree if all the letters of that word is in the tree?

Comment: yes, but in sequence

Comment: So, basically, you have a dictionary, and are looking for all the words that have a particular substring...

Comment: Note, you should add the picture to your questions as opposed to adding a link to it.

Comment: Every node is a letter? You don't have a tree, you have a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Comment: call it trie if you want, but that was the question in the test..

Comment: i added a picture that illustrate the tree

Comment: I think he wants you to embed the picture

Comment: It's not really a trie.   A trie typically has an array or linked list of next node pointers per node, as opposed to being binary tree.   In this model, you couldn't have the words mom, mum and man in the same tree....

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzTdN.jpg this is the link for the picture of the tree in the example

Comment: @John I see, however I'm used to seeing binary 'search' trees, and here each subbranch does have a common prefix (even though there might be duplicate parallel branches).

Answer (score 1):

So basically, because the tree in your image does not appear to be ordered or balanced, so you would have to search every branch until either you hit a match, or you hit a leaf.   Once you hit a match, you could ignore all the branches underneath because they're irrelevant.   But outside of this, you don't know the depth of the tree, so you can't end searching prematurely based on depth.

So, your algorithm would be something to the effect of:

```
// returns the number of matches
// matchMask is a bitmap of the string sublengths that match so far...
int search(const char *substr, int substrlen, uint32_t matchMask, node_t *node) {
     uint16_t newMatchMask = 0;
     int bit;
     ASSERT(substrlen < (sizeof(matchMask)*8));
     if (node == NULL) {
         // hit a leaf, stop return 0
         return 0;
     }

     while (bit = LSB(matchMask) != -1)
     {
         if (node->ch == substr[bit+1])
             newMatchMask |= (1 << (bit+1));
     }
     if (node->ch == substr[0])
          newMatchMask;

     if (newMatchMask & (1 << strlen)) {
         // found a match, don't bother recursing
         return 1;
     } else {
         return 
            search(substr, substrlen, newMatchMask, node->left) +
            search(substr, substrlen, newMatchMask, node->right);
     }
}
```

Note, that I had to do some funky bitmap stuff there to keep track of the depths matched so far, as you can match a partial substring along the way.   `LSB` is assumed to be a least-significant-bit macro that returns -1 if no bits are set.   Also, this is not tested, so there might be an off-by-one error in the bit masking, but the idea is still there.

-- EDIT --

oops, forgot to stop recursing if your node is blank...   Fixing

Answer (score 0):

You want to enumerate all words in the tree and check at each end of word if you have a match using `strstr()`.

The keywords to search for would be *tree walking tree depth-first*.

The semantics of your tree structure are confused.  To clarify your question, you should enumerate all words present in the tree by hand, then write a function that walks the tree and prints the same list, the final step is easy: instead of printing them, check if the string matches with `strstr` and count the matching words.

Comment: Yes, it is the task in the test, but I couldn't solve it yet. I tried to do what you said but without success

Comment: You should post the exact definition of the tree structure and semantics.

Comment: typedef struct tnode {
 char ch;
 struct tnode *left;
 struct tnode *right;
}TNODE;

typedef struct tree {
 TNODE *root;
}TREE;

Comment: Yes, but what is a word for you in your tree? Any path from the root?

Comment: In the tree example posted, are `amo` and `ab` considered words present in tree?

Comment: Sorry, but the semantics of your tree are confused.  To clarify your question, you should enumerate all words present in the tree by hand, then write a function that walks the tree and prints the same list, the final step is easy: instead of printing them, check if the string matches with `strstr` and count the matching words.